# Project Euler 12, Java solution attempt, recursion error?

Tags: java, recursion

I just need some pointers on improving my solution to the problem. Please don't hand me the solution, as I would like to accomplish that myself. Here is my attempt at solving Project Euler Prob 12, using recursion. The problem asks for the first triangular number that has over 500 divisors.

I don't see anything wrong with it; Eclipse doesn't show any error as well. It just keeps on running without reaching the answer.

```
public class P012 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int m=2;
        int c=1;
        int d=(c*(c+1)/2);

        while (numDivs(d,m)<=499) {
            c++;
            d=(c*(c+1)/2);
        }
        System.out.println(d);

    }

    public static int numDivs(int a, int b) {
        int foo=2;
        while (b < a/2) {
            if ((a%b)==0)
                foo++;
            b++;
            numDivs(a,b);
        }
        return foo;

    }
}
```

Comment: And what is Project Euler 12?

Comment: When stuff keeps running, you can often use the debugger or System.out to check the values and see if they are what you expect.

Comment: yup this one takes a looong time , have u tried waiting?

Comment: @duffymo: He has b++ before calling the recursive method.

Comment: This should terminate. Just the performance is not optimal.

Comment: @gtgaxiola: https://projecteuler.net/problem=12

Comment: Funny enough, that is the lowest-numbered problem I haven't solved yet. I should look into that myself now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a pretty naive algorithm. You should improve on that probably.

1) Are you sure the answer will fit into an `int`?
Think about it, do some tests.

2) You can e.g. use the prime factorization of the
number to counts its divisors. If the prime factorization is:
`M = p1 ^ k1 * p2 ^ k2 * ... pN ^ kN`,
then the count of the divisors of `M` is:
`(k1+1)*(k2+1)*...*(kN+1)`.

3) You may need to sieve all primes up to a given pre-chosen value
(e.g. up to 10,000,000) in order to faster implement 2).

4) Even with this naive approach, I don't think your method
is logically correct i.e. test it on a few small numbers first.

See also:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

I just calculated the problem myself, and I can say your approach would mostly work. The numbers aren't that big as I assumed in the beginning. The biggest problem is the unnessecary recursive call in numDivs. Just calculate it with a while-loop (you also need only one parameter for the function in that case). then it all does need around a minute or two to run (you need to calculate a bit more than 12000 triangle numbers, that is not that bad). Your numDivs has an error though, you should break your while-loop at b <= a/2 (or you don't count a factor in some cases). With these fixes your approach should work. Good luck.

EDIT: With the fixes I mentioned I tried your program - and it get's to the same result as mine, so you already found the solution only have some minor bugs. Funny number by the way, the resulting number. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your recursive call to numDivs().  That has calculated the number of divisors indicated by its parameters and has returned that value.  What are you doing with the returned value?  Is that *really* what you want to do with it?

Another, separate, hint.  Your loop limit of a/2 is too high.  You can reduce it.

Comment: Yes, he wants the number of divisors, as this is what the problem  asks for: https://projecteuler.net/problem=12 Also a/2 is correct as limit, as not only prime divisors are searched for.

Comment: Every divisor he finds automatically has a counterpart: the divisors come in pairs.  You only need to count the lower of each pair and add 2 when you find it -- making allowance for square numbers.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it is not needed. I just calculated it with the simple approach and it needed only  around a minute.

Comment: My Java implementation runs in just over half a second.  The questioner's problem is because he is not counting divisors correctly and so never reaches 500.  Thus his program never stops and will eventually fill heap space.

Comment: The biggest problem in his implementation is the unnessecary recursive call, he could just simply cut it out. And yes, in some cases it counts the factors wrong, to be precise if the triangle number is even he misses one. He might catch the right on luck anyways or a later one with 501 factors though.