# Project Euler Prob 12, take 2

Tags: java

I am here again at my wits end wrestling with Project Euler Problem 12. It asks for the first triangle number to have over 500 divisors. https://projecteuler.net/problem=12

Here is my previous attempt:

[Project Euler 12, Java solution attempt, recursion error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486750/project-euler-12-java-solution-attempt-recursion-error)

I received many great pointers which I diligently tried to apply.

Thanks to your replies, now I can: sieve prime numbers up to a very high value and do prime factorization of any number and count the divisors.

But I just can't tie these techniques with the problem of finding the triangle number with 500 divisors. So I have sieved the primes up to a large number, then what should I do? I factorized any number and counted its divisors, then how do I use this to solve the problem?

I went back to my old trial solution and cleaned up the code. Now it can find triangle numbers with low divisor count. But up to 500, the compiler keeps on running.

Here is my cleaned up solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long c=2;
    long d=(c*(c+1)/2);

    while (numDivs(d)<=500) {
        c++;
        d=(c*(c+1)/2);
    }
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(c);

}

public static long numDivs(long a) {
    long foo=2;

    for (long b=1;b*2<=a;b++ ) {
        if (a%b==0) 
                foo++;
    }

    return foo;

}
```

Is there any way I can speed up this process? Or should I just give up on this solution?

Thanks for reading and I will appreciate all the input.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code rather than a specific answerable question

Comment: What is a triangle number?

Comment: @CommuSoft [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Well, that's a triang**ular** number, just wanted to check before investing effort in something that turned out to be something different ;).

Comment: @CommuSoft it's explained in the link to the problem in project euler as well :)

Comment: There are lots of optimizations to do here. Basically, the slower part of your app is `numDivs` method. I would recommend you to focusing on optimizing this by using Sieve of Eratosthenes or another technique to only use prime factors rather than going for all the numbers between 1 and half of the parameter.

Comment: I think, that first you have to factorize your number. For example for 6 you have to take {2 -> 1, 3 -> 1} (because 2*1 + 3*1 is 6), then you have to take the values (1) and add 1 to it, so it's [2, 2], then you have to multiply values in the array, e.g. 2*2, which gives 4, and this is the number of divisors. If you use your sieve you should factorize number quickly. Another example could be 12, it's {2 -> 2, 3 -> 1}, so take values (2, 1) and add 1 to each, gives [3, 2] -> 3 * 2 is 6 (number of divisors). PS. I've just noticed it's the first answer in the linked question.

Comment: @PeeHaa not really, considering the program actually doesn't run if you read the full OP. I agreed with you at first until I saw that point as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing, one can do, is count the number of divisors twice as fast, simply by cutting at `sqrt` of the number:

```
public static long numDivs(long a) {
    if(a == 1)
        return 1;
    long num = 2;
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(a);
    if(sqrt*sqrt == a) {
        num++;
    }
    for (long b = 2;b < sqrt; b++) {
        if (a%b == 0) {
                num += 2;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

**Rationale:** if the dividor is larger than the square root of the number, it has a co-dividor who is less, instead of counting them separately, you can count them both at once.

This definitely has an impact because `numDivs` will now have a timecomplexity *O(sqrt n)* instead of *O(n)*.

Comment: Thanks. What is "num" is being used for?

Comment: @Circadian: `num` is the number of dividers, fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the algorithm you're trying to apply is quite naive.

Check my code, which uses, I think, better approach.

## Finding Primes

```
private static List<Integer> sieve(int maxPrime) {
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[maxPrime];
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);
    for (int i = 2; i * i < maxPrime; i++) {
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            primes.add(i);
            for (int j = i; i * j < maxPrime; j++) isPrime[i * j] = false;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

## Factorization

Here we get a map, where key is the factor, and value is the number of times it occurs.

```
private static Map<Integer, Integer> factorize(List<Integer> primes, int number) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = new HashMap<>();
    int tempNumber = number;
    for (Integer prime : primes) {
        while (tempNumber % prime == 0) {
            tempNumber = tempNumber / prime;
            if (factors.containsKey(prime)) factors.put(prime, factors.get(prime) + 1);
            else factors.put(prime, 1);
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

## Counting Divisors

```
private static int countDivisors(Map<Integer, Integer> factors) {
    int result = 1;
    for (Integer c : factors.values()) {
        result *= c + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

## The execution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_PRIME = (int) Math.sqrt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    List<Integer> primes = sieve(MAX_PRIME);

    int triangularNumber = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        triangularNumber += i;
        Map<Integer, Integer> factors = factorize(primes, triangularNumber);
        int total = countDivisors(factors);
        if (total > 500) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number " + triangularNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to calculate the triangle number anew each time, you can just add on c as

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n
```

so code wise

```
long c=2;
long d=(c*(c+1)/2);

while (numDivs(d)<=500) {
    c++;
    d += c;
}
```

which should hopefully cut down on the time taken